# Android : 400 bad request on XML post

Tags: android, xml, post, http-post, bad-request

i'm working on android REST application. I'm trying to perform a POST method with XML content in doBackground() but the server returns **a 400 bad request**

my code of my client :

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {

@Override
protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // serialisation xml
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        serializer.write(profil, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String serializedProfil = out.toString();

    // creation de la requete post
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://X.X.X.X:8080/webservices/inscription");

    try {
        post.addHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(serializedProfil);
        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

the header of the service i try to reach...

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String inscrire(@Context HttpServletRequest req, JAXBElement<User> JaxbUser) {
           ...
}
```

any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: `inscrire` != `inscription`

Comment: incrire = method name, 
incription = URI ( @Path("incription") with Jersey framework)

Comment: for FSM sake dump `serializedProfil` to logcat and check if it is XML

Comment: yes, XML looks correct.

<User>
   <dateDeNaissance>15/10/2014</dateDeNaissance>
   <genre>H</genre>
   <identifiant>maya</identifiant>
   <mail>maya</mail>
   <password>maya</password>
</User>

Comment: i tried and the server return an http 406 Inacceptable....

Comment: serialization is wrong? ... should it be `<User dateDeNaissance="15/10/2014" genre="H" identifiant="maya" mail="maya" password="maya" />` ? check by harcoding this value to serializedProfil

Comment: serialization and my xml seem to be good.
i think "400 bad request" means the request signature is malformed. the server sends this error before trying to read my xml content...